# SendMessage WinApi в photoshop

Tags: c#, winapi, photoshop, cursor

Пишу программу, которая должна взаимодействовать с photoshop(Это не плагин). Использовал Cursor.Position=, чтобы двигать курсор. Но он не работает в photoshop(программа не может сдвинуть курсор, пока photoshop открыт). Посоветовали использовать WinApi. Но тоже не работает. Пробовал посылать WM_MOUSEMOVE,WM_LBUTTONDOWN. Везде, кроме photoshop'а работают оба варианта. В photoshop ни один. МБ не те сообщения посылаю...
(Готов сменить язык, если необходимо)

Дополнение: На win7 все работает, на win10 photoshop, spy++ и диспетчер задач не дают двигать курсор.

Comment: на сколько я знаю, в фотошопе имеется свои скрипты которыми можно запрограммировать нужные действия. Для чего нужна прослойка в виде шарпа и винапи? https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-scripting-guide-2019.pdf

Comment: Посмотрите функцию mouse_event. Не факт, что поможет, но она более низкоуровневая чем все эти SendMessage

Comment: Посмотрите еще SendInput

Comment: И еще попробуйте вместе с WM_LBUTTONDOWN посылать WM_LBUTTONUP

Comment: @Vasek ,SendInput не сработал. WM_LBUTTONDOWN присутствовал. Просто не указал

Comment: @Zergatul , mouse_event(0x01, 20, 20, 0, 0); не работает

Comment: @andrew , мне нужно, чтобы курсор взаимодействовал со всем, а не только с photoshop(пишу эмулятор тачпада/граф.планшета)

Comment: тогда нужно искать именно что команды отвечающие за стилус граф.планшета. Там же есть и сила нажатия, и угол поворота стилуса... это же не просто мышка. Возможно, используя правильные команды не будет проблем и с фотошопом

Comment: Можно через spy++ посмотреть какие месаги летят окну и потом попробовать их воспроизвести

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил. WinApi работает, но не забываем запускаться от имени администратора, чего я не сделал